# Why Angular post function work on Chrome but not on Firefox?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox

I have function in my angular service which is calling an API using the POST method.

Function works fine on Chrome but not on Mozilla Firefox.

How to adapt this function for Mozilla ?

Code:

```js
    uri='http://localhost:5000/updateAvatarId/';
     httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      };
    
     changeAvatar(mod_id, avatar_id){
        
        this.http.post(this.uri + mod_id + '/' + avatar_id, this.httpOptions).subscribe();
      }
```

Comment: IT looks fine as is.  Can you quantify how it didn't work?  Was there an error in the console?  Did you get back unexpected results?

Comment: There is no error in console it just don't call post method at all.

Comment: Are you sure that the changeAvatar function is called when the web is running firefox? try by adding a console.log inside the funciton.

Comment: Yes, and parameters which function gets are correct.

Comment: I just found a  problem. In my component function before I made a call to service I call window.locatio.reload(), and that made a problem for Mozilla.